# How to rotate pixels of contour or approximate polygon of contour in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

After finding contours in image, consider I have contours pixels and approximate polygon of it.

I want to rotate contours pixels or the approximate polygon of contour with a given angle. Is it possible in OpenCV?

Comment: are you interested in the new orientation of the contour, or do you want to rotate the "pixels" of that contour (for example: rotate one single object within the image and the rest should stay unchanged)?

Comment: Yes, definitely I want to rotate "pixels" of that contour. As your example: "rotate one single object within the image and the rest should stay unchanged"

Comment: what should be done with pixels that were occluded before the rotation? My suggestion: Create a filled mask from the contour (e.g. fillpoly function). rotate the whole image and rotate the mask. copy the pixel from the rotated image where the rotated mask is set the original image. To find pixel that were occluded before the rotation, compare rotated and unrotated masks.

Comment: Thank you @Micka. However when I rotate whole image, contours sometimes goes out of frame. So I need to translate them to a visible part of frame. For example to origin. I found [this link](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/How-to-move-Contour-td6211447.html) but there isn't any answer to that question. How can I do that?

Comment: By the way my rotation matrix returned according to contour center. `Mat matRotation = getRotationMatrix2D(Point(center[i].x / 2, center[i].y / 2), angle, 1);` Should I rotate according to image center?
`Mat matRotation = getRotationMatrix2D(Point(image.cols  / 2, image.rows / 2), angle, 1);`

Comment: To test whether the contour is still in the image after rotation just rotate the vertices first and test their coordinates against the image borders. If you have to translate before the rotation you have to translate the mask too. Rotation matrix with center of contour should be ok!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how you can rotate an object within the image

this is the input image with known object/contour position (the colored thing there)

[image]

```
int main()
{
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("rotateObjects_input.png");

    std::vector<cv::Point> myContour;
    myContour.push_back(cv::Point(100,100));
    myContour.push_back(cv::Point(150,100));
    myContour.push_back(cv::Point(150,300));
    myContour.push_back(cv::Point(100,300));

    cv::Point2f cog(0,0);
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<myContour.size(); ++i)
    {
        cog = cog + cv::Point2f(myContour[i].x, myContour[i].y);
    }
    cog = 1.0f/(float)myContour.size()*cog;

    std::cout << "center of gravity: " << cog << std::endl;


    // create and draw mask
    cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(input.size(), CV_8UC1);
    cv::fillConvexPoly(mask,myContour,255);

    // create rotation mat
    float angleDEG = 45;
    cv::Mat transformation = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(cog,angleDEG,1);
    std::cout << transformation << std::endl;

    // rotated mask holds the object position after rotation
    cv::Mat rotatedMask;
    cv::warpAffine(mask,rotatedMask,transformation,input.size());
    cv::Mat rotatedInput;
    cv::warpAffine(input,rotatedInput,transformation, input.size());

    cv::imshow("input",input);
    cv::imshow("rotated input",rotatedInput);
    cv::imshow("rotated mask",rotatedMask);

    // copy rotated object to original image:
    cv::Mat output = input.clone();
    rotatedInput.copyTo(output, rotatedMask);

    cv::imwrite("rotateObjects_beforeHolefilling.png", output);

    // now there are pixel left from the old object position.
    cv::Mat holePixelMask = mask & (255-rotatedMask);
    // we have to fill those pixel with some kind of background...
    cv::Mat legalBackground = (255-mask);
    //cv::erode(legalBackground,)

    // fill holes. here you could try to find some better background color by averaging in neighborhood or sth.
    cv::Vec3b lastLegalPixel(0,0,0);
    for(unsigned int j=0; j<mask.rows; ++j)
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<mask.cols; ++i)
        {
            if(holePixelMask.at<unsigned char>(j,i))
            {
                output.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i) = lastLegalPixel;
            }
            else
            {
                if(legalBackground.at<unsigned char>(j,i))
                    lastLegalPixel = input.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i);
            }
        }



    cv::imshow("holes before filling", holePixelMask);
    cv::imshow("legal background", legalBackground);

    cv::imshow("result", output);

    cv::waitKey(-1);
    return 0;
}
```

this is the output before hole filling

[image]

and this is after hole filling

[image]